# I tried uploading a pdf file from vue.js to laravel. Is there a way to assign a file to an object? Or is there any other way?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I used `@change="pdfFile"` to upload files from my `vue.js` to `laravel`. When I store the file in an object and `console.log` that object, it displays the file in console. But when I upload the file using `axios`, it says, `pdf file required`. How do I read the pdf file and send it from vue.js to laravel.

HTML Code

```
<input type="file" class="forms__resume--upload" @change="pdfFile" accept="application/pdf">
```

Script Code

```
pdfFile (e) {

  this.pdfFiles = e.target.files[0]
  axios
    .post('/formdata/store', {
      file: this.pdfFiles
    })
    .then(res => {
      alert('successfully posted')
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
}
```

Comment: have you try this https://serversideup.net/uploading-files-vuejs-axios/

Comment: I have tried using `this.$refs.file.files[0]`, but it still says `pdf file required`.